# 4D Convolution with 4D input and 4D weights Python

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to write CNN myself(with Tesorflow,Keras,PyTorch) in python. And I'm teaching at https://www.coursera.org/learn/convolutional-neural-networks/ . 
CNN is:

`In deep learning, a convolutional neural network (CNN, or ConvNet) is a class of deep neural networks, most commonly applied to analyzing visual imagery. They are also known as shift invariant or space invariant artificial neural networks (SIANN), based on their shared-weights architecture and translation invariance characteristics. They have applications in image and video recognition, recommender systems, image classification, medical image analysis, natural language processing, and financial time series.`

I've created zero_padding and single_conv_step. Now I'm stopped at Convolutional Layer feed forward. I wrote it,but without any vectorization. And as you know without it Conv2D layer will compute very late. I've tested numpy.convolve,scipy.signals.fftconvolve,spice.ndimage.filters.convolve and ... . But they din't help me.
My function(Conv2D) takes params A_prev(Prev_Layer),W(weights),stride,padding.
A_prev.shape = (training_exam,height,width,channel)
W.shape = (filter_size,filter_size,channel,filter_num)
They are what will be convolved. A_prev will be zero_padded with argument padding.
I need in vectorized version of algorithm.

Code:

```py
  def conv_forward(A_prev,W,b,stride,pad):
    (m, n_Hp, n_Wp, n_Cp) = A_prev.shape
    (f,f,n_Cp,n_C) = W.shape
    n_H = int((n_Hp - f + 2*pad)/stride+1)
    n_W = int((n_Wp - f + 2*pad)/stride+1)
    Z = np.zeros((m,n_H,n_W,n_C))
    A_prev_pad = zero_pad(A_prev,pad)
    for i in range(m):
      a_prev_pad = A_prev_pad[i]
      for h in range(n_H):
        vert_start = stride*h
        vert_end = vert_start+f
        for w in range(n_W):
          hori_start = stride*w
          hori_end = hori_start+f
          for c in range(n_C):
            a_slice_prev = a_prev_pad[vert_start:vert_end,hori_start:hori_end,:]
            we=W[:,:,:,c]
            bi=b[:,:,:,c]
            Z[i,h,w,c] = conv_simple_step(a_slice_prev,we,bi)
    cache=(Z,W,b,stride,pad)
    return Z,cache       
def zero_pad(X,pad):
  x_pad = np.pad(X,((0,0),(pad,pad),(pad,pad),(0,0)),mode='constant',constant_values=(0,0))
  return x_pad

def conv_simple_step(a_prev,W,b):
  s = np.multiply(a_prev,W)
  Z = s.sum()
  Z = Z+ float(b)
  return Z
```

So,summary, my problem is how to convert code above to vectorized version(with using numpy functions only, as they forks very fast)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What exactly is your question? Also please use paragraphs to structure your question, so that we can understand what is going on.

Comment: @Erich Hi,thanks, I've described my problem at the end of question and added more code,my problem is how to convert code above to vectorized version(with using numpy functions only, as they forks very fast)

Comment: Can you take negative vote from my question,please)?